# Compressing a folder into a ZipFile

Tags: java, file

I have this Java method to upload a file. I am trying to cater for users trying to upload a folder by compressing that folder into a zip file and upload it instead. For some reason in my case `file.isDirectory()` and `file.isFile()` are not working correctly.. even though the filename does not contain any extension, `file.isFile()` is returning true and `isDirectory()` returns false. Also `directory.list()` is also acting weird by returning null.

What can be the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

```
public File uploadFile(FileItem item, String filename, int ticket_id) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream fileContent = null;
    File file = null;

    try
    {
        //fullpath returns C://MyDocuments//zerafbe//Documents//apache-tomcat-7.0.29//webapps//attachments//t50\test

        StringBuffer fullPath = new StringBuffer();
        fullPath.append(Attachment.attachments_path); 
        fullPath.append("t"); 
        fullPath.append(Integer.toString(ticket_id)); 
        fullPath.append(File.separator);
        fullPath.append(filename);

        System.out.println("filename " + filename);

        file = new File(fullPath.toString());

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            // if directory does not exist, create it
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }

        if (file.isFile())
        {
            // if file is not a folder                  
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileContent = item.getInputStream();

            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            // read all the file and write it to created file
            while ((read = fileContent.read(bytes)) != -1) 
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        }
        else if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            ZipFile appZip = new ZipFile(fullPath.toString());
            appZip.generateFileList(file);
            appZip.zipIt(filename + ".zip");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        LogFile.logError("[FileUpload.uploadFile()] " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        LogFile.logError("[FileUpload.uploadFile()] " + e1.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (out != null)
        {
            out.close();
        }

        if (fileContent != null)
        {
            fileContent.close();
        }
    }

    return file;
}
```

This is the ZipFile class I am using

```
public class ZipFile 
{
    List<String> fileList = null;
    String source_folder = "";

    public ZipFile(String source_folder)
    {
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.source_folder = source_folder;
    }

    public void zipIt(String zipFile)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String source = "";

        try
        {
            try
            {                     
                source = source_folder.substring(source_folder.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, source_folder.length());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                source = source_folder;
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (String file : this.fileList)
            {
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(source + File.separator + file);
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);

                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source_folder + File.separator + file);

                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                in.close();
            }

            zos.closeEntry();
            //remember close it
            zos.close();
        } 
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();   
        }
    }

    public void generateFileList(File node)
    {
        // add file only
        if(node.isFile())
        {           
            fileList.add(generateZipEntry(node.toString()));
        }

        if(node.isDirectory())
        {           
            String[] subNode = node.list();

            if (subNode != null) {

                for(String filename : subNode)
                {
                    generateFileList(new File (node, filename));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String generateZipEntry(String path)
    {
        return path.substring(source_folder.length() + 1, path.length());
    }
}
```

`file.list()` is being done in the `generateFileList` method in `ZipFile` class. I know this is returning null since I tried detecting whether the file is a folder or a file by using `filename.indexOf(".")` instead of `isDirectory()` and `isFile()` since they were not working. But I wish I had an explanation for this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You create parent directory and test existence first, then you work with data. That is weird. Does it exist before running or not?

Comment: I test existence of the folder I want to upload a file to. I am trying to handle a case scenario where the uploaded file is a folder

Comment: Who shall create this upload directory? If nobody then Java will create regular file and not directory.

Comment: This path will be present all the time:  'C:\MyDocuments\zerafbe\Documents\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\attachments' but I need to upload files relative to some id so Java is creating for example: \t50\filename in attachments folder.

Comment: I was writing about "t50/test" directory. If it does not exist prior your execution, then file.isDirectory() will never return true.

Comment: hmm and can I do something for Java to create only a folder or is it impossible? :/

Comment: file.mkdirs(); will create it. I think that there is an issue with your concept or its description. Please describe all concept, how file or directory for upload is created.

Comment: I did an if statement and tried: file.mkdirs() instead of file.parentFile.mkdirs() and the folder I wanted was created. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    // if directory does not exist, create it
    file.mkdirs();
}
```

will create directory and test file.isDirectory() will return true

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the path?

```
C://MyDocuments//zerafbe//Documents//apache-tomcat-7.0.29//webapps//attachments//t50\test
```

You are mixing backslash with slash...

Comment: just noticed that and changed the path to all \ but still the same problem :/

Comment: path is now: C:\MyDocuments\zerafbe\Documents\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\webapps\attachments\t50\test and obviously I modified ZipFile to source = source_folder.substring(source_folder.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, source_folder.length());

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code block

```
ZipFile appZip = new ZipFile(file.toString());
appZip.generateFileList(file);
appZip.zipIt(filename + ".zip");
```

with a local folder and it's working perfectly. I think you are passing a invalid path. This may be the cause *isFile* or *isDirectory* methods are acting strangely. Try to add a validation statement at the starting of *generateFileList* method using *File* API:

```
if(!node.exists) {
     // return some flag to signify error OR throw a suitable Exception   
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks blackSmith. You verified that my problem is what @Leos Literak is saying. when I am creating the directory with the folder, java creates a File for me and therefore isDirectory() always will return false

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String compressData(String srcDir) {

         String zipFile = srcDir+".zip"; 
                try {

                    // create byte buffer
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);

                    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

                    File dir = new File(srcDir);

                    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

                    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

                        System.out.println("Adding file: " + files[i].getName());

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i]);

                        // begin writing a new ZIP entry, positions the stream to the start of the entry data
                        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));

                        int length;

                        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }

                    zos.closeEntry();

                        // close the InputStream
                        fis.close();
                    }


    // close the ZipOutputStream
                    zos.close();

                }
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Error creating zip file" + ioe);
                }
                return zipFile;

            }
```